# DB not connecting on Namespro linux server

Tags: database

I am not a developer nor do I have a technical background, striving to solve a lingering issue with our it/hosting company. This means I unfortunately can't supply code for reference; simply seeking community support if anyone has encountered a similar issue.

We launched a new site that is configuring on the Namespro server but not connecting to the Craft Pro CMS DB. It seems to be a port or permissions error but our hosting company hasn't been able to resolve the issue for a couple of months now. The site has been live and encountered zero issues launching on our developer's digital ocean droplet.

Any thoughts??? Don't want to waste anyone's time but hopeful someone has encountered this issue with Namespro before.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take Craft out of the picture... can you connect with the credentials you're using with a MySQL client?  i.e. Sequel Pro, Navicat, command line, etc.

Comment: Yes, it is connecting with the MySQL client.

Answer (score 1):

So if it can't connect to the database, then one of the following is not right in the `config/db.php` file:

- `server` - usually it's `localhost` but perhaps they provide an external MySQL server?
- `database` - the name of the database
- `user` - the user authorized to access the database
- `password` - the password used to connect to the database

FWIW, this type of issue (and also this lack of support) would make me want to keep the site on the Digital Ocean server, and not move it to Namespro.